# how to efficiently vectorize a function and retrieve values from it

Tags: python, performance, vectorization

Suppose I have a very computationally expensive function `f(x)`. I want to compute some values of it, and then just access them instead of evaluating the function every time with new `x` values.

See the following simple example to illustrate what I mean:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 6001)
fx = x**2
x = np.round(x, 3)

#I want to evaluate the function for the following w:
w = np.random.rand(10000)

#Rounding is necessary, so that the w match the x.
w = np.round(w, 3)

fx_w = []
for i in range(w.size):
    fx_w.append(fx[x==w[i]])

fx_w = np.asarray(fx_w)
```

So, I'd like to have `f(w)` computed from the values already generated for `x`. Of course, a `for` loop is out of the question, so my question is: how can I implement this somewhat efficiently?

Comment: sorry about that. I have corrected it.

Comment: In your example, x doesn't have duplicates and matches produce at most 1 element arrays. Is that always the case?

Comment: Yes, that is always the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`searchsorted`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find the corresponding indices of your prepared function array. This will be an approximation. Rounding is not necessary.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 6001)

fx = x ** 2

w = np.random.rand(10000)
result = fx[np.searchsorted(x, w)]

print('aprox. F(x):', result)
print('real F(x):', w ** 2)
```

Output

```
aprox. F(x): [0.140625   0.904401   0.535824   ... 0.896809   0.158404   0.047524  ]
real F(x):   [0.1402803  0.90385769 0.53581513 ... 0.89625588 0.1579967  0.04714996]
```

Your function has to be much more computationally intensive to justify this approach

```
%timeit fx[np.searchsorted(x, w)] #1000 loops, best of 5: 992 µs per loop
%timeit w ** 2                    #100000 loops, best of 5: 3.81 µs per loop
```

Comment: what do you mean by the number of loops? number of times you run the program? In my case, the function is more computationally expensive than ```x**2``` , but also I might have millions of values to ```w``` that need to be evaluated. I will run some experiments to see if doing this is truly an improvement in efficiency.

Comment: *Binary search is used to find the required insertion points* in `searchsorted`, that is `O(n * log(m))` complexity, where `n` is the size of the new values, `m` the size of the prepared function values. Your function has to be ~300x more complex than squaring plus the time that is required to contruct the array `fx`.

Comment: Yes, I did some experiments and came to the same conclusion. For some functions that involve convolution, and other complex operators this solution might worth it. But in my case it isn't. It is nonetheless nice to learn this ```searchsorted``` function!

Comment: Perhaps wait to accept this answer to motivate others to come up with more efficient solutions.